# How to call multiple methods asynchrounosly with different implementation

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous

I am trying to call one method 12 times asynchronously. But before the call I am setting something different for each method call. How can I do this in a more elegant way.

I am using spring as well.

I am aware of @async but how can I change the body 12 times ?

```
Callable<Object> task4 = () -> {

        CallContextHolder.setContext(callContext);
        try {

            Object m = dbQuery(userId);
            if (m == null){
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
            return m;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("task interrupted", e);
        }
    };
    Callable<Object> task5 = () -> {

        CallContextHolder.setContext(callContext); //here is the difference in every task
        try {

            Object m = dbQuery(userId);
            if (m == null){
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
            return m;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("task interrupted", e);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like the following method

```
public Callable<Object> getCallable(CallContext context, String userId) { //replace types fro parameters to appropriate
    return () -> {
      CallContextHolder.setContext(callContext);
      try {
        Object m = dbQuery(userId);
        if (m == null){
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        return m;
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("task interrupted", e);
      }
   };
}
```

And use it like this

```
Callable<Object> call1 = getCallable(callContext, userId);
Callable<Object> call2 = getCallable(callContext, userId);
```

You can try to use some type of loop to generate those callables and store them in a list.